# how springboot return html rendered rather than literal?

Tags: spring-boot, model, return, thymeleaf

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/member")
public class OAuthController {


@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/name")
public String abcCallback(@RequestParam String code,Model model){ 
abc=service.getname(code);
model.addAttribute("abc",abc);

return "/main.html";
}

}
```

i omit extra.
i want to return model to `main.html [located in src/main/resources/templates/main.html]`
but when i run this. it shows literally /main.html
should i change my annotation?
i'm confusing

change return `"main.html"`, return "main"
change annotation `@restController`

but doesn't work

Comment: 1. It should be `@Controller` *not* `@RestController` 2. *No* `@ResponseBody` but a "view name"... 3. probably (assuming default/normal/quickstart) better return (just) `"main"`!(without path`/` and suffix ..assuming there is a "main.html" in src/main/resources/templates ..and thymeleaf configured;)

Answer (score 1):

`@RestController` is having both `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` .
The issue here is `@ResponseBody` which needs to be removed.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/member")
public class OAuthController {



@GetMapping("/name")
public String abcCallback(@RequestParam String code,Model model){ 
abc=service.getname(code);
model.addAttribute("abc",abc);

return "main";
}

}
```